# Flutter: Getting relative height of widget for vericalDivider

Tags: flutter, user-interface, vertical-alignment, space

Im building a screen where a widget is supposed to look like a Tweet. Im trying to implement the vertical bars seen under profile pictures with the following:

```
Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                VerticalDivider(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  thickness: 10,
                  width: 20,
                ),
                //make a widget that looks like twitter composing tweet
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 20,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.imageUrls[0]),
                ),
                //add a gray line that runs down the middle of the screen
                VerticalDivider(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  thickness: 10,
                  width: 200,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the dividers are invisible. Wrapping the divider with a specified height makes it look like this:

[image]

It is now visible, but obviously expands outside of the original size of the widget. Is there any way to pass the size of the parent into the VerticalDivider so i knows how much space it has to work with?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include more about the parent widget? sample widget from scaffold body will be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `Row` with the `IntrinsicHeight` widget. It will set the rows height based on its tallest child (here the Container with height = 200). Of course in your example you don't know the tallest child's size before layout, I used the container simply to give you an example. `IntrinsicHeight` is relatively expensive to use but the right choice for such use cases (see its [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html)).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  child: VerticalDivider(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    thickness: 10,
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Container(height: 40, width: 40, color: Colors.blue),
                Expanded(
                  child: VerticalDivider(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    thickness: 10,
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.white,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: While closer, this still does not solve the problem. I cannot set my verticalDivider in a sized box because i do not know what the height of the widget will be, and I want it to stretch until the end of the widget.

Comment: You can wrap it in a `Flexible` / `Expanded` as I did for the second `VerticalDivider`. This way you don't assign any static height.